# Disable prefetching on intel processor on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, intel

I am trying to disable the prefetcher on a Xeon chip running 20.04 using msr-tools. It relies on the msr folders being at `/dev/cpu/CPU_NUM/msr`. However, those folders aren't there for some reason. Is there another way to disable prefetching on 20.04? I have looked for the msr folders elsewhere and I can't find them. Are they located elsewhere in 20.04? Is there a different tool for ubuntu or a more up to date tool that I should use?

Thanks!!

Comment: Reading here https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/Disabling-HW-prefetcher/td-p/1176690 the OP was showing that they were running this in a VM which does not have the same way to disable the prefetch.  You're not running this in a VM are you?

Comment: @Terrance correct. I am not running a VM

Comment: Those files and the use of msr-tools requires the msr kernel module to be loaded first, `sudo modprobe msr`.

Comment: @DougSmythies That worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files, `/dev/cpu/CPU_NUM/msr` and the `msr-tools` provided read and write msr commands that manipulate them interface to/from the kernel via the `msr` module, which must be loaded before use of the rdmsr or wrmsr commands. Error reporting is non-existent or not great and so it might not be apparent what is wrong if the module is lot loaded.

Example (no msr module, then with msr module):

```
doug@s18:~$ ls -l /dev/cpu
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 184 Oct 19 08:34 microcode
doug@s18:~$ sudo rdmsr 0x198
rdmsr: open: No such file or directory
doug@s18:~$ sudo modprobe msr
doug@s18:~$ ls -l /dev/cpu
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      60 Oct 19 08:37 5
crw------- 1 root root 10, 184 Oct 19 08:34 microcode
doug@s18:~$ ls -l /dev/cpu/0
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 202, 0 Oct 19 08:37 msr
doug@s18:~$ sudo rdmsr 0x198
279f00002e00
```

**Important note for the future:** In upcoming kernels (as of 5.9, I think), user write access to the MSRs (Machine Specific Registers) is being restricted. Access will need to be enabled. I use the grub command line option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= "msr.allow_writes=on"
```

The write msr ability can also be changed after boot via `/sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes`. Example:

```
doug@s18:~$ sudo cat /sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes
off
doug@s18:~$ sudo wrmsr 0x19c 0
wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted
doug@s18:~$ echo on | sudo tee /sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes
on
doug@s18:~$ sudo cat /sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes
on
doug@s18:~$ sudo wrmsr 0x19c 0
doug@s18:~$
```

Note: I know that writing 0 to 19C (IA32_THERM_STATUS) is O.K.